# Intervention Image - save to variable in base64 encoded format

Tags: laravel, base64, intervention

I'm using Laravel with image manipulating package [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/introduction).

I want to save cropped image to variable and then to DB but can't find in documentation how to export result as string. Here's my code:

```
$img = Image::make($uploadedImage);
$img->crop(160, 210);
$imageEncoded = // ?
```

There's [`save()`](http://image.intervention.io/api/save), but it only saves to file.

How can I export modified Intervention Image to string variable? (`data:image/jpeg;base64,…`)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use [encode](http://image.intervention.io/api/encode) for that.

```
$data = (string) Image::make('public/bar.png')->encode('data-url');
```

Comment: Thank you @Drown, exactly what I needed.

Comment: this is for creating a data-uri that is specifically for img src tags, if you want the plain base64, try $b64 = base64_encode($img->encode()->encoded);

Comment: @parse Your proposed edit would have been better as separate answer, in my opinion.